# TweenLite inside of react project not working after build

Tags: jquery, reactjs, gsap

I am having an issue on my production build where GSAP TweenLite plugin is not working and throwing an error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'scrollTo' on 'Window': parameter 1 ('options') is not an object.`. My local development server seems to work fine.

Local:
`console.log(com.greensock.plugins.ScrollToPlugin.version); -> //1.9.2`

Production 
`console.log(com.greensock.plugins.ScrollToPlugin.version); -> //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined at <anonymous>:1:50`

devDependencies
`"gsap": "^2.1.3",`

Component:

```
import { TweenLite } from "gsap/all";
..

const handleOnClick = id => {
    let headerHeight = 90; // height of the sticky nav
    let paddingTop = 20; // add some padding.
    TweenLite.to(window, 0.5, { scrollTo: { y: `#${id}`, offsetY: headerHeight + paddingTop } });
};

//Map function
...
<li key={item.id} onClick={() => handleOnClick(item.id)}>
    <span className="text">{item.text}</span>
    ...
</li>
...
```

Comment: This was answered [on the GSAP forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/23806-tweenlite-inside-of-react-project-not-working-after-build/).

Comment: Thank you this was me, https://greensock.com/forums/topic/23806-tweenlite-inside-of-react-project-not-working-after-build/?do=findComment&comment=112986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Greensock forums : https://greensock.com/forums/topic/23806-tweenlite-inside-of-react-project-not-working-after-build/?do=findComment&comment=112883

```
import { TweenLite, ScrollToPlugin } from "gsap/all";
const plugins = [ScrollToPlugin];
```